# How to parse date string with '0' day to Date in moment.js?

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I have a string representation of date in TypeScript like this: '05-00-2018'.
And would like to transform it to JavaScript Date object using momentjs. I tried this:

```
new Date(moment.utc('05-00-2018', 'MM-DD-YYYY').format('MM-DD-YY'))
```

But it gives me '*Invalid Date*'. Could anyone advice me?

Comment: Why are you working with a date that doesn't exist?

Comment: Date comes from a 'pseudo' date picker where user could not select a day, so day is '00' by default in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to get it working with the following solution:

```
moment.utc('05-00-2018', 'MM/00/YYYY').startOf('day').toDate()
```